# Is there a better way to write this short script?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
string = "rRdDbB"
for letter in string:
    print(letter)
for letter in string:
    for subletter in string:
        print(letter+subletter)
for letter in string:
    for subletter in string:
        for subsubletter in string:
            print(letter+subletter+subsubletter)
```

I would like to continue this until I get string lengths of 10, but my approach seems very tedious.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product()`.

Comment: Working code that might be improved belongs on Code Review, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for count in range(1, 11):
    for characters in itertools.product(string, repeat=count):
        print ''.join(characters)
```

I should also add that 6**10 is a really big number.  Are you really trying to print them, or is this loop for some other purpose?

Comment: Hey, this loop is intended to generate 2by2 cube algorithms that I can use in another function to perform the permutations. I would like the end result to give me the shortest algorithm to solve the cube... I have noticed that this probably isn't an ideal approach, but I haven't found many tutorials on this.

Comment: Ah, you're solving a Rubik's Cube.  Now the notation makes sense.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [power set](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Here is an implementation:

```
def powerset(in_a):
   if len(in_a) <= 1:
      yield in_a
      yield []
   else:
      for out_a in powerset(in_a[1:]):
         yield [in_a[0]] + out_a
         yield out_a

s = 'rRdDbB'
a = list(powerset(list(s)))
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[['r', 'R', 'd', 'D', 'b', 'B'], ['R', 'd', 'D', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'd', 'D',
'b', 'B'], ['d', 'D', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'D', 'b', 'B'], ['R', 'D', 'b',
'B'], ['r', 'D', 'b', 'B'], ['D', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'b', 'B'], ['R',
'd', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'd', 'b', 'B'], ['d', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'b', 'B'],
['R', 'b', 'B'], ['r', 'b', 'B'], ['b', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'D', 'B'], ['R',
'd', 'D', 'B'], ['r', 'd', 'D', 'B'], ['d', 'D', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'D', 'B'],
['R', 'D', 'B'], ['r', 'D', 'B'], ['D', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'B'], ['R', 'd',
'B'], ['r', 'd', 'B'], ['d', 'B'], ['r', 'R', 'B'], ['R', 'B'], ['r', 'B'],
['B'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'D', 'b'], ['R', 'd', 'D', 'b'], ['r', 'd', 'D', 'b'],
['d', 'D', 'b'], ['r', 'R', 'D', 'b'], ['R', 'D', 'b'], ['r', 'D', 'b'], ['D',
'b'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'b'], ['R', 'd', 'b'], ['r', 'd', 'b'], ['d', 'b'], ['r',
'R', 'b'], ['R', 'b'], ['r', 'b'], ['b'], ['r', 'R', 'd', 'D'], ['R', 'd',
'D'], ['r', 'd', 'D'], ['d', 'D'], ['r', 'R', 'D'], ['R', 'D'], ['r', 'D'],
['D'], ['r', 'R', 'd'], ['R', 'd'], ['r', 'd'], ['d'], ['r', 'R'], ['R'],
['r'], []]
```